# How do you make this mock work?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

The goal is to mock method readInput of InputReader class to return a specific value when I run a unit test. If I run the code below, then I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

Which means that the mock did not work. How do I make it work in Java?

```
package foo;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


public class InputTest {
    private int getInput() {
        return new InputReader().readInput();
    }

    @Test
    public void getInputTest() throws Exception {
        InputReader sc = mock(InputReader.class);
        when(sc.readInput()).thenReturn(1);

        assertEquals(1, getInput());
    }
}

class InputReader {
    int readInput() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a mock InputReader, but the method you call (getInput()) doesn't use that mock instance. It uses `new InputReader()`. That other instance is another, not mocked instance of InputReader.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly create an InputReader in your getInput method. So the mock you create will not be used anywhere. To use it, you will have to call

```
@Test
public void getInputTest() throws Exception {
    InputReader sc = mock(InputReader.class);
    when(sc.readInput()).thenReturn(1);

    assertEquals(1, sc.readInput());
}
```

To otherwise use the mock you might create amember variable to use within getInput. Or use a dependency injection framework like Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually mocking the class `InputReader` instead of method `InputTest#getInput`. You can see the difference:

```
@Test
public void getInputTest() throws Exception {
  InputReader sc = mock(InputReader.class);
  when(sc.readInput()).thenReturn(1);

  assertEquals(0, getInput());     // no mock
  assertEquals(1, sc.readInput()); // mock
}
```